# XCode Magical Record, MR_findByAttribute - looking for strings with certain word (regex?)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, magicalrecord

I have an API, from which I load Shop objects.
Shop object has NSString *assortment field, containing products you can buy in shop, in my syntax it's eg. "water,milk,potatoes,bread,ketchup".

```
NSString *assortment = @"water, milk, potatoes, bread, ketchup";
```

I load shops from my local database to an NSArray *shops.

```
NSArray *shops = [Shop MR_findAll];
```

I want to find all objects in my shops array (using MR_findByAttribute maybe?) that contain word "bread" in their assortment field.

I know I can split my string and check for every single assortment position - but that sounds not intuitive to me. I feel like there's better solution, maybe:

```
NSArray *shopsWithBread = [Shop MR_findByAttribute:@"assortment" withValue:@"<bread regex?>"];
```

Do you know any nice way to do it? Do you have maybe another good idea how to find all those shops? Maybe you're sure it can't be done this way and I have to write search engine myself?

Thank you in advance for all answers.
Karol

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found the solution - I'm using predicate.

```
NSPredicate *breadSearchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"assortment contains[cd] %@", @"bread"];
NSArray *shopsWithBread = [Shop MR_findAllWithPredicate:breadSearchPredicate];
```

assortment is my field name; contains[cd] is a kind of instruction, checking for containing a string give - here @"bread".

NSPredicate - nicely explained here: http://nshipster.com/nspredicate/